# How to count based on one value in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I've below data and I would like to do grouping on JobName, but I would need all the data columns.

```
JobName  rule  name …….
Job-A     1     PDF
Job-A     1     PDF
Job-A     1     PDF
Job-B     2     ADF
Job-B     2     ADF
Job-C     3     OPS
Job-D     4     NPS
Job-D     4     NPS
Job-D     4     NPS
Job-D     4     NPS
```

Result should be

```
JobName  rule  name  ….  count
Job-A     1     PDF     3
Job-B     2     ADF     2
Job-C     3     OPS     1
Job-D     4     NPS     4
```

Comment: based on your sample data, it seems that grouping on `JobName`, `rule`, and `name` would give the same result as just grouping by `JobName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing some requirement, you just need to aggregate by all three columns, and then take the count of each group:

```sql
SELECT JobName, rule, name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY JobName, rule, name;
```

Comment: I've almost 15 fields in my table and other fields holds different values. Still this is good ways to do it ?

Comment: Yes, still a good way, barring something about your data which you're not revealing to us here.